# Issue using firebase-admin - dependencies were not found

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js, firebase-admin

I am developing an application by nuxtjs. I have installed the Admin SDK for Node.js to validate the user's token in the server side but when I import firebase-admin in the project I have the next issue. I have installed the modules child_process fs net tls but it didn' work.

> WARNING  Compiled with 4 warnings
>   20:30:20  warning  in ./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js
>
> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> warning  in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js
>
> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> warning  in
>   ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js
>
> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> warning  in ./node_modules/hash-stream-validation/index.js
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fast-crc32c' in
>   'C:\Users\ARSENIO\Desktop\Development\nuxt\project4\node_modules\hash-stream-
>   validation'
>
> ERROR  Failed to compile with 38 errors
>   20:30:20 These dependencies were not found:
>
> - child_process in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js,
>     ./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js
> - fs in ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/src/file.js, ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/src/bucket.js and 34 others
>
> To install them, you can run: npm install --save child_process fs

The package.json file is:

```
    {
      "name": "project4",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "My gnarly Nuxt.js project",
      "author": "Arsenio Aguirre",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "nuxt",
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "start": "nuxt start",
        "generate": "nuxt generate",
        "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
        "precommit": "npm run lint"
     },
    "dependencies": {
      "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
      "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-beta",
      "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
      "child_process": "^1.0.2",
      "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
      "firebase": "^5.5.3",
     "firebase-admin": "^6.0.0",
     "flag-icon-css": "^2.9.0",
     "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
     "fs": "0.0.1-security",
     "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
     "net": "^1.0.2",
     "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
     "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
     "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
     "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
     "tls": "0.0.1",
     "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.0"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "eslint": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "2.6.2",
    "prettier": "1.14.3"
 }
```

}

Comment: just bumped in a similar issue, you may find this useful: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/610